# Correct use of the word "unprecedented"

Tags: grammar

Is it valid to say "an unprecedented meeting occurred ... "?

To me this sounds cumbersome.

Comment: Your suggested version has 50% more words.  How is that less cumbersome?

Comment: Your title puzzles me. I cannot think of a way of using *unprecedent* as a verb in the active voice. Though I suppose *precedent* could be. *His actions will precedent disaster*?

Comment: @ws2 what does precedent mean in "his actions will precedent disaster"?  There is no verb here, only an adjective formed from a noun by adding "ed"https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ed#Etymology_3.

Comment: The OED recognises a verb *precedent* -  *1. trans. To provide with a precedent; to use as a precedent; to support with or justify by a precedent. Usu. in pass. Cf. precedented adj. 1959   Art Educ. 12 11/1   This is taking place to a degree that has never before been precedented.*

Comment: @phoog Suppose someone starts using a two-way road as a one-way street, and removes the signs which warn otherwise. Then it could act as a precedent to disaster - i.e. 'it could precedent disaster'. But I admit you have got me wondering about this.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to explain what you find "cumbersome" about it?

Comment: I think most US listeners would find it odd to hear "precedent" used as a verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of [unprecedented](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unprecedented)  is:

> - having no previous example: unprecedented economic growth. (AHD)
> - having no precedent; unparalleled (Collins)

I don't see any problem with your sentence.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unprecedented%20meeting%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunprecedented%20meeting%3B%2Cc0): *unprecedented meeting* ( you can find a number of similar usages here)

- The resolutions of this unprecedented meeting were by nature purificatory; ([Metropolis and Province)](https://books.google.it/books?id=UqqNqzHvvLoC&pg=PA63&dq=%22unprecedented%20meeting%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=-vuYVZGuMeW17gadpqOIAw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22unprecedented%20meeting%22&f=false)
- “News” of this unprecedented meeting was reported next day in the NewYork Times.([The Civil Sphere](https://books.google.it/books?id=TV89AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT299&dq=%22unprecedented%20meeting%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=-vuYVZGuMeW17gadpqOIAw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22unprecedented%20meeting%22&f=false))